# Was Mein Kampf prohibited in occupied France?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, france

Because the Nazis did not want the French to know about the anti-French attitude of Hitler?

Comment: Given that it was published 15 years before the occupation of France, I'd imagine that the French knew the gist of the content even if they hadn't read it themselves. Also, since the Germans did little to endear themselves to the French during the occupation, I don't imagine that the content of Mein kampf would have made much of a difference towards the French view of their invaders.

Comment: @Steve Bird I have just faced this claim online so I want to verify.

Comment: @Anixx "Is it true that..." questions are usually a good fit for https://skeptics.stackexchange.com - if you can still find the website with that claim in your browser history.

Comment: Trivial; enter the question in google and the answer pops up within the first five results.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Must say that noting interesting is appearing in my top ten or even twenty results - what does Google know about your search patterns that are not true of mine? ;-)

Comment: Is your question whether it was prohibited, or was that a fact, and the question is whether the motivation you've described is correct? Or both?